# JSPM bundle vs requireJs confusion

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, jspm

I am new to jspm. I have requrieJs background.

Is it true that jspm while bundling compiles all dependencies into one big file ? like jquery, jquery-ui,bootstrap, databases to other 50 plguins used in project ?

If yes, then What is benefit ? would it not be much faster to fetch items when required like in requrieJs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default jspm does not bundle your dependencies. Every dependency is imported on its own. So if you have three files, say main.js, smth.js and jquery.js, jspm will require them one by one as soon as System.import is called. For static dependencies (like ES6 modules), it happens before the code is executed. But you can also require additional modules at runtime.

The idea behind is that bundling is not really required with HTTP/2. jspm knows the entire dependency tree and it can request all of the dependencies in parallel. Then all files will be delivered over the same network connection which should be pretty the same as if you were bundling them at the build time.

But since HTTP/1 is still to common, jspm offers bundle & build CLI. But those command only put everything in one big file by default. The process is highly configurable. You can exclude certain dependencies such as jquery and put them in a separate bundle or even load jquery from CDN. See https://jspm.io/docs/production-workflows.html#creating-a-bundle for more info how exclude/include modules.

Comment: Thankx. I have  more questions 
 (1)  If I use http/2 server , i dont need to bundle at all and it works like requirejs ? right ?
 (2)  Can I see imported js css files in DOM ?

Comment: 1) no, you can skip bundling but I recommend checking if performance is good enough 2) afaik no, but you will see what has been loaded in network tab of developer tool

Comment: Ok I understand. If I want to skip bundling, I will need a grunt task to minify all js css files in project, even insalled with ```jspm install ``` right ? Is there a way JSPM can do minification but not bundling ?

Comment: Becuuse in my test example , i see jquery is not minified that was installed using jspm install jquery

Comment: Are you using jspm 0.16 or 0.17 beta? For 0.16 you could try the following: jspm bundle jquery jquery-bundle.js --inject --minify

This command should bundle jquery module into jquery-bundle.js and --inject tells it to modify the jspm.config.js automatically so that the jquery will be taken from the bundle when you require it in the code. I think --minify flag is also supported in this case.

Comment: But without any bundling I believe the source files will not be minified unless  the source code is already minified.

Comment: Ok i get it . So I can create a bundle with all vendors with --inject which could be minified then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156764/discussion-between-oleksii-rudenko-and-django).